# NodeJS error message - UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY - attempting LDAPS connection

Tags: node.js, ldapjs

I have LDAP connections working properly with [node-ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/).  I am trying to implement LDAPS connections with node-ldapjs.  The setup/configuration I am using is equivalent to the solution which was described as being successful by another individual and was posted here - https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/issues/307.  My code is shown below.  When I execute the code below, I get the following message:

`{[Error: unable to get local issuer certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'}`

Here is the full stacktrace -

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1022:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
    at TLSWrap.TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:428:38)
```

On the same client computer which my nodeJS app is running on, LDAPS binds to the remote DC are successful when I test with [LDP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772839(v=ws.10).aspx) or [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

Can anyone help me to determine (1) what is the root cause of the error message above and (2) how can I resolve this issue ?

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var tls = require('tls');
var ldap = require('ldapjs');

var tlsOptions = {
host: 'FQDN',
cert: fs.readFileSync('mycert.pem'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('my-root-CA.cer'),
rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var server = tls.connect(636,tlsOptions,function() {
console.log('tls connect');
console.log('client connected', server.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.pipe(server);

    if ( server.authorized )
    {
            var client = ldap.createClient({url: 'ldaps://domainControllerIP:636',tlsOptions:tlsOptions});
            client.bind(username, password, function (err) {
            cb(err === null, err);
            });
            //Perform LDAP search operation
            var opts = {
             filter: '(&(objectclass=organizationalRole))',
             scope: 'sub',
             attributes: ['cn']
            };

            client.search('dc=domain,dc=local', opts, function(err, res) {
            res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
                          console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
            });
            res.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
                          console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
            });
            res.on('error', function(err) {
                         console.error('error: ' + err.message);
            });
            res.on('end', function(result) {
                        console.log('status: ' + result.status);
            });
       });
  }
});
server.setEncoding('utf8');
server.on('data',function(data){
console.log('data section: ',data);
});

server.on('secureConnect',function(data){
console.log('secure connect section: ',data);
});

server.on('error', function(error) {
console.log('client closing...',error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem eyeballing your code.  The raw error as reported is propagating back up from the `openSSL` layer (of Node.js), and typically arises because the certificate cannot establish its trust chain; in an LDAPS context, I'd expect the problem was validating the server certificate at the client end.

This error can arise with self-signed certificates, or more generally if the trust chain depends upon the correct installation of intermediate certificates to complete the trust from a certificate authority root (assuming nothing has expired).  And, in a corporate environment, this can be complicated further by the presence of proxies/firewalls, and their (mis-)configuration.

I'd suggest you concentrate your efforts on diagnosing/validating the combination of your certificates and dependencies to the trusted root CAs along the secure connections that need to be established.  In this regard, other tooling, such as `curl` or `openssl` tools (and similar can be helpful).

Comment: How would you curl an `ldaps://` endpoint?